# Right Bar Button item not working

Tags: iphone, ios5, navigationbar

Actually i am placing a bar button on right side of navigation bar, it's not working. But when i use it as left bar button item, it's working fine. I am  using ios5.

It was also not working when i have both button left and right bar button. Then i set the frame for both, then these are working. But when i have only one button on right side, it's not working.

```
 UIButton *but1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];//customising map button.

but1.frame = CGRectMake(270,0,50,40);       

[but1 addTarget:self action:@selector(clicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];//on cilcking an map button clicked method is called.

buttonRight = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:but1];//setting map button on Navigation bar.

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonRight;//setting button on the Right of navigation bar.
```

how to trace out this error?

Comment: Gopesh would you please share what was your problem and how did u solve that? I have this problem now. When i tried setting right bar button inside a navigationcontroller which is inside a popover controller, the right button item is not displaying.

Comment: wht's the problem you are getting @selvin

Comment: The problem was, the right bar button was not visible. I solved it by setting the frame of the navigational controller in viewDidLoad. Thanks for asking :)

Comment: good selvin..setting frame make the button visible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]
                          initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 45)];
    [toolbar setBarStyle: UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
    // create an array for the buttons
    NSMutableArray *buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    // create a standard BarButtonItem
    UIBarButtonItem *SettingsBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_setting.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                   target:self
                                   action:@selector(ActionMethod:)];
    [buttons addObject:SettingsBtn];
    [SettingsBtn release];

    // put the buttons in the toolbar and release them
    [toolbar setItems:buttons animated:NO];
    [buttons release];

    // place the toolbar into the navigation bar
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                              initWithCustomView:toolbar]autorelease];
    [toolbar release];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"edit" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: self action: @selector(edit_details)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
```

Comment: suraj actually it was the frae issue.

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift 4.2** code:

In the View did load function

```
let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "edit", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(edit))
 navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
```

Function definition goes here:

```
@objc func edit() {
    // Body definition
}
```